# How to get activity context in ViewModel Android?

Tags: android, firebase, mvvm, firebase-authentication

I am using MVVM. I want to implement Firebase Auth in app. But to implement it I need an activity context in my repo class. How can I get it from ViewModel or is there any simple method available?

Here is the firebase code I need to implement:

```
 PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber("+91"+phone,        // Phone number to verify
            60,                 // Timeout duration
            TimeUnit.SECONDS,   // Unit of timeout
            (Activity) context,               // Activity (for callback binding)
            new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
                @Override
                public void onVerificationCompleted(@NonNull PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) 
               {
                    signInWithPhoneAuthCredential((Activity)context,phoneAuthCredential);
                }

                @Override
                public void onVerificationFailed(@NonNull FirebaseException e) {
                    setLoginFailed(e);

                }

                @Override
                public void onCodeSent(@NonNull String s, @NonNull 
                PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken) {
                    super.onCodeSent(s, forceResendingToken);
                    loginResponse.setOnProgress(false);
                    loginResponse.setStatus(true);
                    loginResponse.setCodeVerified(false);
                    loginResponseLiveData.setValue(loginResponse);
                    verificationId =s;

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, ViewModel objects are not supposed to reference anything that has to do with the Android platform APIs, especially Activity objects.  You would not want a ViewModel to retain (and leak) an Activity across orientation changes.  Retaining Activity objects in a ViewModel is a huge anti-pattern that should be avoided.

Instead, you should use a different version of that Firebase API.  Choose one of the alternatives that do not take an Activity, according to the [API documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/PhoneAuthProvider).  Once the API is complete, you can bubble a callback up to the hosting activity to start any other activities.

Comment: yes, I was also thinking that I am violating the law of MVVM...i didn't find an alternative inAPI doc.. so I should handle it in activity!!?

Comment: In my answer, I linked to API documentation that gives you multiple alternatives of `verifyPhoneNumber` that do not use an Activity.  I'm recommending that you use one of those altenratives.

Answer (score 1):

- If you work not related to any `UI` then you can use `AndroidViewModel`  instead of `ViewModel`
- In `AndroidViewModel` there in one important default parameter `ApplicationContext`
- Or if you want any specific activity References then use `LiveData<YourActivity>` and set class reference when you initialize ViewModel in class

Comment: i can't use android view model as I need activity context for firebase..
can you briefly explain LiveData<YourActivity> thing

Comment: OK in you View Model Class Add This first

    var activityReference: MutableLiveData<BaseActivity>? = MutableLiveData()

and in your Activity Class add This line

viewModel.activityReference?.value = this@SignUpActivity //(your class reference)

then in your view model you have reference of your current activity

Comment: What is `AndroidViewModel`?  How to use that.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, according to [official view model guidelines](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel):

> Caution: A ViewModel must never reference a view, Lifecycle, or any class that may hold a reference to the activity content

So in accordance with your MVVM architecture, **don't pass your activity context to a ViewModel**.

I guess in that method you want to implement you do not specifically need an activity context. You could also use the `context` of your application.

Follow these 3 steps of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5114361/13138026) to get access your Application `context` statically:

1. create Application class which references the `context` on create

   ```
   public class MyApplication extends Application {

       private static Context context;

       public void onCreate() {
           super.onCreate();
           MyApplication.context = getApplicationContext();
       }

       public static Context getAppContext() {
           return MyApplication.context;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Declare your application class in your Manifest

   ```
   <application android:name="com.xyz.MyApplication">

   </application>
   ```
3. Access this context statically inside your repository class

   ```
   MyApplication.getAppContext()
   ```

There is also the possibility to access the application context via `AndroidViewModel` class. But I guess you usually do not want to initialize your repository from your ViewModel.

Comment: storing context like this may result in memory leak..also I have already tried using AndroidViewModel but as you know it provides application context, not activity context...
so firebase giving exception..and ask to cast the context from application to activity

Comment: Then what about Doug Stevenson's suggestion, does the API also provide such a method without requiring the activity context? It would probably be the best solution if you do not need to worry about messing with the context at all